# Which doxygen tags are allowed for contracts?

Tags: solidity

Where can I find the list of doxygen tags that are allowed for contracts?

[This documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/layout-of-source-files.html#comments) states:

> Additionally, there is another type of comment called a natspec comment, for which the documentation is not yet written. They are written with a triple slash (///) or a double asterisk block(/** ... */) and they should be used directly above function declarations or statements. You can use Doxygen-style tags inside these comments to document functions, annotate conditions for formal verification, and provide a confirmation text which is shown to users when they attempt to invoke a function.

then I tried some tags but got errors like this:

```
DocstringParsingError: Doc tag @tag not valid for contracts.
DocstringParsingError: Doc tag @section not valid for contracts.
DocstringParsingError: Doc tag @version not valid for contracts.
```

Before manually trying some more - is there a list somewhere that lists all allowed doxygen tags?

Comment: You tried something with `solidity` ? Apparently they refer to doxygen documentation / doxygen style tags / commands but havn't implemented all of them. So not a doxygen problem (the doxygen documentation you can find through www.doxygen.org). You probably need a list of available `solidity` tags.

Comment: Yes - was no doxygen problem and I really needed the list of solidity tags.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is [Ethereum Natural Specification Format](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Natural-Specification-Format) that has most information on the topic.

At the moment, these are (copy-paste-format):

- `@title` - A title that should describe the contract
- `@author` - The name of the author of the contract
- `@notice` - Explain to a user what a function does
- `@dev` - Explain to a developer any extra details
- `@param` - Documents a function parameter
- `@return` - Documents the return type of a function

---

But do take a look at the link, it's got much more - including scope that I had to edit out above.

Comment: Thanks - but it seems etherscan has a different list: https://twitter.com/mr_ligi/status/1008742212627296257